# Creating UIHint attributes on the fly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I want to inject a UIHint attribute into a model object on the fly. I have been using the ICustomTypeDescriptor to create a class that will inject a UIHint into an instance of an object:

```
public sealed class UIHintDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private string PropertyName;
    private string HintValue;

    public UIHintDescriptionProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider parent, string propertyName, string hintValue)
        : base(parent)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
        this.HintValue = hintValue;
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return new UIHintDescriptor(base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance), this.PropertyName, this.HintValue);
    }
}

public sealed class UIHintDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private string PropertyName;
    private string HintValue;

    internal UIHintDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent, string propertyName, string hintValue)
        : base(parent)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
        this.HintValue = hintValue;
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        // Enumerate the original set of properties and create our new set with it
        PropertyDescriptorCollection originalProperties = base.GetProperties();
        List<PropertyDescriptor> newProperties = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in originalProperties)
        {
            if (pd.Name == this.PropertyName)
            {
                Attribute attr = new UIHintAttribute(this.HintValue);
                var newProp = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(typeof(object), pd, attr);
                newProperties.Add(newProp);
            }
            else
            {
                newProperties.Add(pd);
            }

        }

        // Finally return the list
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(newProperties.ToArray(), true);
    }

}
```

I then set this in my controller using:

```
UIHintDescriptionProvider provider =
                new UIHintDescriptionProvider(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(PageContentItem)), "Text",
                                              "wysiwyg");
            TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(provider, item);
```

Inspection in the controller of this object using the functions of TypeDescriptor indicate that this attribute has indeed been set however it does not appear in my view at all. Stepping through the MVC3 source shows all the other attributes but not the one I have just set.

Does MVC3 do any caching of object type descriptions in the background that could account for that fact?

Any other suggestions for injecting an attribute into an object instance at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of 'timing'. 
Try using a custom ModelMetadataProvider to programmatically set model property attributes like 'UIHint' or 'DisplayName' or ...
Have a look [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx).